# RFC Connection "Bad Variant Type"

Tags: asp.net, abap, saprfc, sap-dotnet-connector

Well, I'm using SapConnector dll to make RFC from .Net to SAP. When I use dll in a Windows form application, everything is fine, but when I try to make connection in ASP.Net Web Site or Web Application, I get an error;

> Bad Variant Type

My code:

```
if (Connector.StartConnection())
    {
        try
        {
            Connector.AddFunction("Z_SCL_SOMETHING");
            Connector.AddFunctionInputParameter("WPERNR", "999999");
            Connector.CallFunction();
        }
   }
```

I get the error in this line;

```
Connector.AddFunction("Z_SCL_SOMETHING");
```

Another weird case is that, in Windows Forms Application when I make this call in **backgroundWorker** I get  the same error again.

Any idea about this error ?

Comment: is this an exception? Could it be an x86/x64 issue?

Comment: Yes this is an exception and no i tried but not about that issue I think.

Comment: is there an innerException providing more information?

Comment: This looks quite helpful (but I wouldn't know because I don't use ASP/.NET and so on): http://scn.sap.com/message/2802706