# VBA program executing SAP RFCs works in Excel 2016 on-prem, but not in Office 365 (Run-time error 20080008...Bad Variant Type)

Tags: excel, vba, office365, saprfc

Let me first say that I saw the other two threads that mentioned this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56459823/sap-rfc-connection-with-vba-bad-variant-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454574/sap-rfc-connection-bad-variant-type), but they didn't help me solve my problem.

I've been testing a program for several weeks in the on-prem Excel 2016 environment (32-bit) with no problems. My company is making the move to Office 365 soon, so I decided to test it over there as well. On that system, I'm getting a run-time error on the line `Functions.Connection = objConnection`

```
Option Explicit
Public Functions As SAPFunctionsOCX.SAPFunctions
Private LogonControl As SAPLogonCtrl.SAPLogonControl
Private objConnection As SAPLogonCtrl.Connection
Public Func As SAPFunctionsOCX.Function
Public Commit As SAPFunctionsOCX.Function
Public TableFactory As SAPTableFactory
Public silentLogon As Boolean
Public tblReadTableOptions, tblReadTableFields, tblReadTableData As SAPTableFactoryCtrl.Table

Sub ExtractProjectData()
    If objConnection Is Nothing Then LogonToSAP
    InitiateSAPVariables
    Set Func = Functions.Add("BBP_RFC_READ_TABLE")
    Set tblReadTableOptions = Func.Tables("OPTIONS")
    Set tblReadTableFields = Func.Tables("FIELDS")
    Set tblReadTableData = Func.Tables("DATA")

    'extract/transform data from SAP tables

End Sub

Function InitiateSAPVariables()
    Set Functions = Nothing
    Set TableFactory = Nothing
    Set Func = Nothing
    Set Functions = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")
    Set TableFactory = CreateObject("SAP.TableFactory.1")
    Functions.Connection = objConnection 'run-time error here in Office 365 but not in on-prem
End Function

Function LogonToSAP()
    Dim establishConnection As Boolean
    silentLogon = false
    Set LogonControl = CreateObject("SAP.LogonControl.1")
    Set objConnection = LogonControl.NewConnection
    objConnection.Client = "###"
    objConnection.Language = "EN"
    objConnection.SystemNumber = "##"
    objConnection.User = ""
    objConnection.Password = ""
    objConnection.HostName = "###############"
    objConnection.System = "###"
    objConnection.ApplicationServer = "###.###.#.##"
    establishConnection = objConnection.Logon(0, silentLogon)
End Function
```

A quick check of objConnection tells me that logon was successful...so I know that part is working on 365. For some reason though, it doesn't like assigning the `Connection` property of the `Functions` SAPFunctionsOCX.SAPFunctions object in the 365 environment (please feel free to correct my verbiage on that...I know it's not quite right).

Note that I'm not seeing any reference issues nor am I getting any compile errors in either environment. The first sign of trouble is on execution of `Functions.Connection = objConnection`

There's one more twist here and that is that I have another older VBA program that logs into SAP and runs remote function calls that doesn't use SAPFunctionsOCX.SAPFunctions, but rather declares variable R3 as `Public R3 As Object` and then sets R3 later in the logon code as `Set R3 = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")`...it does not use OCX. In other words, the old routine uses late binding. When the Functions object (R3 in this case) is set this way, I am able to run RFCs in both on prem and Office 365 environments.

```
Function LogonProdSAP(Optional SuppressLoginScreen As Boolean)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    '**********************************************
    'Create Server object and Setup the connection for DEV
    '**********************************************
    Set R3 = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")
    If SuppressLoginScreen Then
        R3.Connection.System = "###"
        R3.Connection.HostName = "###################"
        R3.Connection.SystemNumber = "##"
        R3.Connection.Client = "###"
        R3.Connection.User = "##########"
        R3.Connection.Password = "#########"
        R3.Connection.Language = "EN"
'        Call Logger("LogonProdSAP>  " & GetUserName)
    End If
    LogonProdSAP = R3.Connection.logon(0, SuppressLoginScreen)
    If LogonProdSAP <> True Then MsgBox ("Logon error"): Exit Function
End Function
```

I could just go back to doing it this way, but I'd rather not have to reconfigure all of the code I just set up. In addition, I prefer binding early so Intellitype works to show all properties/methods available to that object. I'm sure there are other benefits as well.

What do I have to do to get the early-binding technique to work on Office 365?

Comment: Can you do `Set Functions = New SAPFunctionsOCX.SAPFunctions` instead of using `CreateObject()` two lines above the error. It seems like a strange mix of early and late binding in the same codebase. I don't know if it will help, but it might...

Comment: `Set Functions = New SAPFunctionsOCX.SAPFunctions` doesn't rectify...same error on same line.

Comment: a few more differences...stdole2.tlb (OLE automation reference) is stored in the sysWOW64 folder on the on-prem system and in the System32 folder on the 365 system.

Comment: the on-prem system stores the Office-related references (Office object library, Excel object library, and VBA in the Program Files (x86) folder...the 365 system stores them in the Program Files folder (no x86).

Comment: @JNevill Just following up on this...zero progress has been made and I could really use a good lead. Thanks!

Comment: I've never written my own DLL, but it look's like this is what is going to be required ... http://mikejuniperhill.blogspot.com/2017/06/excelvba-multi-threading-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the fact that your Office is in 64 bits version, and SAP GUI for Windows up to version 7.60 is in 32 bits (next SAP GUI version 7.70 should be in 64 bits, so it should work again).

You have a workaround to make VBA work with SAP GUI 32-bits DLL, by using [DLL Surrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), i.e. by editing the Windows Registry of all incompatible SAP GUI DLL. The original solution [was proposed here at SAP Community](https://answers.sap.com/questions/10687512/connect-excel-2010-64-bits-with-sap.html?childToView=10701970#comment-10701970).

To simplify the task, you may create [my .REG file](https://answers.sap.com/comments/13152790/view.html), execute it to update automatically the Windows Registry, and your VBA macro should then work.

I duplicate here my .REG file:

```
; ====================================================================================
; SAP Logon Unicode Control %ProgramFiles(x86)%\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\wdtlogU.ocx {0AAF5A11-8C04-4385-A925-0B62F6632BEC}
; ====================================================================================

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\AppID\{0AAF5A11-8C04-4385-A925-0B62F6632BEC}]
"DllSurrogate"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{0AAF5A11-8C04-4385-A925-0B62F6632BEC}]
"AppID"="{0AAF5A11-8C04-4385-A925-0B62F6632BEC}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{0AAF5A11-8C04-4385-A925-0B62F6632BEC}]

; ====================================================================================
; SAP Remote Function Call Unicode Control %ProgramFiles(x86)%\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\wdtfuncu.ocx {0AF427E7-03B9-4673-8F21-F33A683BCE28}
; ====================================================================================

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\AppID\{0AF427E7-03B9-4673-8F21-F33A683BCE28}]
"DllSurrogate"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{0AF427E7-03B9-4673-8F21-F33A683BCE28}]
"AppID"="{0AF427E7-03B9-4673-8F21-F33A683BCE28}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{0AF427E7-03B9-4673-8F21-F33A683BCE28}]

; ====================================================================================
; SAP Logon Control (not Unicode) %ProgramFiles(x86)%\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\wdtlog.ocx {B24944D6-1501-11CF-8981-0000E8A49FA0}
; ====================================================================================

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\AppID\{B24944D6-1501-11CF-8981-0000E8A49FA0}]
"DllSurrogate"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{B24944D6-1501-11CF-8981-0000E8A49FA0}]
"AppID"="{B24944D6-1501-11CF-8981-0000E8A49FA0}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{B24944D6-1501-11CF-8981-0000E8A49FA0}]

; ====================================================================================
; SAP Remote Function Call Control (not Unicode) %ProgramFiles(x86)%\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\wdtfuncs.ocx {5B076C03-2F26-11CF-9AE5-0800096E19F4}
; ====================================================================================

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\AppID\{5B076C03-2F26-11CF-9AE5-0800096E19F4}]
"DllSurrogate"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{5B076C03-2F26-11CF-9AE5-0800096E19F4}]
"AppID"="{5B076C03-2F26-11CF-9AE5-0800096E19F4}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{5B076C03-2F26-11CF-9AE5-0800096E19F4}]
```

Comment: Yes, after I posted this I learned that 7.70 will rectify this...I am patiently waiting for the end of the month (https://blogs.sap.com/2020/05/06/sap-gui-for-windows-7.70-beta-program-call-for-participation/)

Comment: I only have one user that this impacts at this point...IT has decided to wait to move her to 365 (64-bit) until we can get 7.70 installed on her system.

Comment: Your answer is the correct one...if you have an IT department that is willing to make changes to the registry as a workaround. Mine isn't. Others might not have that problem, so I'll mark yours as the accepted answer.