# Set objBAPIControl = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")

Tags: vba, authentication, connection, bapi

At line `Set objBAPIControl = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")` I face the runtime error 429

> ActiveX component can't create object.

The script was initially running in a 32 bit system now it is upgraded to 64 bit.

This is the logon script:

```
Private Sub SAP_Initialize_Objects()


 Set objBAPIControl = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")
 Set sapConnection = objBAPIControl.Connection


 bln_SAP_Objects_Initiated = True

End Sub

If sapConnection.IsConnected <> 1 Then
```

Comment: What language, what error message, what two lines? Note that you must have installed SAP GUI for Windows to use `SAP.Functions`.

Comment: Its is a VBA code. I have SAP GUI application installed. However, i get a runtime error 429 "ActiveX component can't create object." The script was initially running in a 32 bit system now it is upgraded to 64 bit
 Set objBAPIControl = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")
This is the line that throws run time error. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MS Office 64 bits (I say "if" because in a 64 bits OS, MS Office 32 bits can be used), and SAP GUI 32 bits, then it won't work by default.

There are 3 possible solutions/workarounds:

- Install SAP GUI for Windows 7.70 which is the first version to be 64 bits
- Use the feature "DLL Surrogate" by changing the registry -> See [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65460025/9150270)
- Convert VBA into VBScript that you run in 32 bits (outside your MS Office application)

  - `Dim <var> As <type>` in VBA ▶ `Dim <var>` in VBScript
  - etc. (search Web for differences, e.g. this (non-exhaustive) [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/30593abb(v=vs.84)))

Comment: The company is not ready to upgrade the SAP to 7.7 for one user.  DLL Surrogate is also not effective. Please explain to convert to VBS.

Comment: Impossible to explain how to convert, as it requires extensive VBA-VBS knowledge, but I added one tip and one link to my answer, to start helping you. Good luck!